# SCSI 'VERIFY' equivalent for NVMe

Tags: storage, scsi, nvme

How to translate plain vanilla scsi verify to NVME?
i.e. verify in SCSI with only st lba and verification length provided and all other fields as 0 (so no data transfer).
How to achieve the same in NVMe?

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent command in the NVMe command set to the SCSI VERIFY command. There is a compare command in NVMe or a read command. For the compare command you need to provide the data to compare against and the read command will return the data which you can ignore but it will still transfer the data, which is the thing you skip with the SCSI VERIFY command.

As far as I recall there were discussions in the NVMe group to add such a command but at least in the NVMe spec version 1.3a this command is not yet defined.